# How to send pdf file to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cors

I want to send an address with the GET method to download the pdf file with Rect js.

fileID contains the address of the file on the server side.

Even with adding { mode: 'no-cors'} l I have an error

```
viewHandler = async (fileID) => {

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/download/'+fileID, {

            method: "GET",

            headers: {

                'Authorization': token ? `Bearer ${token} `: '',

                "Content-Type": "application/pdf"

            }
        },{ mode: 'no-cors'})
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(response => {
            //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
            console.log(response);
            const file = new Blob([response], {
            type: "application/pdf"
            });
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            window.open(fileURL);
        })

        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

      };
```

in node js :

```
var app=express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

    res.setHeader(

        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',

        'OPIONS,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE'

    );

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type , Authorization');

    next();

});
```

in router i have this code:

```
router.get('/download/:fileId',isAuth,Usercnl.getFile)
```

in controller i have this code:

```
   getFile(req,res){
        let fileId=req.param.fileId;
        const src = fs.createReadStream(fileId);

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=sample.pdf',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'Binary'
        });

        src.pipe(res); 
     }
```

but i have this error :

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/download/files/3386822336-teacher.pdf' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
getFilesPage.js:78 TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is just a name for some IP. The port is still different `3000`(client) and `8000`(server). Hence both are considered different servers. Add `http://localhost:3000`to CORS whitelist in your node server to resolve the CORS issue.